# Custom defined file metadata keys [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, exif

I'm currently trying to save a jpeg representation of a UIImage with additional custom metadata (e.g. Thermal temperature statistics etc.). These don't fit within the apple predefined keys (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties), so solutions I've found don't apply to my scenario.

I've tried saving the metadata with the image as a dictionary of keys and values, but the image is saved without the additional metadata.

```swift
func saveImage(imageToSave: UIImage, metadata: NSMutableDictionary) {
    if let data: Data = imageToSave.jpegData(compressionQuality: ThermalImageView.JPEG_COMPRESSION) {
        let fileName = self.buildFileName();
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil)!;
        let uniformTypeIdentifier = CGImageSourceGetType(source)!;
        let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(fileName as CFURL, uniformTypeIdentifier, 1, nil)!;
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, metadata);
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    }
}
```

When I try to read these values back with ExifTool (`exiftool -j filename.jpg`), the metadata is nowhere to be found. I expected this to happen as Apple seems to restrict what keys you can add to your metadata. So, is there a way to do this or should I go another route?

Thanks!

Edit: I think I may be barking up the wrong tree here. It seems like what I actually want to do is modify the header with additional metadata.

Answer (score 0):

`Photos` framework is a way to go when dealing with metadata of assets. Moreover, `PHAsset` is the object you'd like to tinker with. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset
One related question is: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60664

If you still want to have it in your current way, perhaps try this? https://github.com/Nikita2k/SimpleExif

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I'm not looking to store predefined metadata associated with an image in the photos library. I'm looking to upload the image to a server that can later extract the metadata from the image itself using ExifTool. In the library you linked, you can see that they are using the 'allowed' exif keys (e.g. https://github.com/Nikita2k/SimpleExif/blob/master/Classes/ExifContainer.m#L70). I'm looking to define my own keys.

Comment: Hi @Chaz, any update on this? were you able to write custom tags?